# hbase vs cassandra for messaging

Tags: cassandra, hbase

A few years ago, Facebook decided to use hbase instead of cassandra for its messaging system: http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/11/16/facebooks-new-real-time-messaging-system-hbase-to-store-135.html

The main fact why fb uses hbase was that reads are faster than writes in compare to cassandra. Is this fact still true? I am using cassandra 3.0 and when setting read consistency level to ONE or TWO, reads are faster than when setting to ALL.

Now my question is: If Facebook has to decide to use cassandra or hbase in 2016, will its decision still be hbase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra was designed and built originally for optimized write performance.  As versions have been released their has been a lot of work done to increase the read performance so that it is much closer to write performance.  There have been multiple benchmarks and studies done on HBase versus Cassandra but in general they tend to say that performance is about equal to Cassandra being a bit better.  however I always take all of these performance benchmark studies with a grain of salt as you can make anyone the winner depending on how you setup the test.

You will most certainly get faster reads and writes with a CL=ONE than ALL because the coordinator only needs to wait for any of the replicas to respond instead of all of them.  If you are in a multi-DC scenario then LOCAL_ONE will increase the throughput even more.

As for whether or not FB would choose Cassandra over HBase, it is impossible to say because there is so much more to making that decision than just simple performance metrics.  I can say that a messaging use case is one that cassandra performs well.  You can read thier use cases here:

http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/functional_use_cases/messaging/